# Transforming the dependent variable

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

I've got this values for my model selection using the sqrt transformation on my dependent variable:

> tbest<-
>       lm(sqrt(betplasm)~age+sex+betadiet+vituse+calories+quetelet+fiber+smokstat)
>   summary(tbest)

```
Call:
lm(formula = sqrt(betplasm) ~ age + sex + betadiet + vituse + 
calories + quetelet + fiber + smokstat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9.9606 -2.5600 -0.3906  1.8120 19.9045 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 12.8598069  1.9523377   6.587 2.05e-10 ***
age          0.0428111  0.0173890   2.462 0.014388 *  
sex          2.0370310  0.7314292   2.785 0.005698 ** 
betadiet     0.0004384  0.0001768   2.480 0.013705 *  
vituse      -1.3058795  0.4769243  -2.738 0.006553 ** 
calories    -0.0011468  0.0004639  -2.472 0.013996 *  
quetelet    -0.1751747  0.0384254  -4.559 7.54e-06 ***
fiber        0.2191167  0.0562820   3.893 0.000122 ***
smokstat    -0.8808482  0.4717671  -1.867 0.062872 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.954 on 296 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2716,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2519 
F-statistic: 13.79 on 8 and 296 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Checking the Shapiro.test to see if our p-value>0.05 to reject the null hypothesis:

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  rjack
W = 0.94564, p-value = 3.548e-09
```

From my plots, I can tell that my model looks quite normal but according to the shapiro test, my p-value<0.05 suggests to reject the null hypothesis( that my data is normal). Do I accept it as my best model or do I need to transform my dependant variable again?

Comment: 1. what exactly did you test for normality? 2. What plots did you look at?

Comment: @Glen_b I checked QQ plots and histogram as well as jackknife residuals. Should I reject the shapiro test result if I'm satisfied with the normality of my graphs?

Comment: I'm guessing from your output the Shapiro test was performed on jacknife residuals. Note that in large samples it can pick up deviations from normality that may not matter so much for your inference.  What does the QQ plot of them actually look like?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, the shapiro was performed on jackknife residuals. The QQ plots look quite good in the sense of normality.

Comment: I was hoping to discern more precisely the manner of deviation from normality in order to make a more concrete suggestion about whether there was anything to be concerned about. "Looks good" tells me nothing about what deviation the Shapiro Wilk was likely to be picking up.

Answer (score 1):

Normality tests are extremely sensitive to sample size. With a sample size of around 300, even slight deviations from normal will register as "significant".

Personally I never use hypothesis tests for checking normality; I always use diagnostic plots. You say that your plots looked good? What exactly did you look at. Based off your model, I would be examining qqplots to test the assumption of normality.

If your plots show that you have approximately normal data, then I'd be inclined to trust them. They're probably giving you a much better picture than the hypothesis test is.

Comment: I checked QQ plots and histogram which look good. So in this case if I judge my regression model through the plots for the assumption of normality, should i reject the shapiro test?

Comment: Yeah that sounds good. Don't even bother with the Shapiro test